# Composer ErrorException: touch(): Utime failed: No such file or directory

Tags: composer-php

I am attempting to install a Mailchimp php api.

Following the instructions given on their github [page](https://github.com/mailchimp/mcapi2-php-examples), I have managed to download and install cURL which I used to install composer.

Now when I run 'php composer.phar install' in the command line, I get the error: 
[ErrorException]
touch():Utime failed: No such file or directory

I have all paths properly setup.

If someone could tell me what this even means and how to correct

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error recently [touch(): Utime failed: Operation not permitted] this is as a result of permissions uner which your using composer

either run composer with elevated rights (not ideal) or more prefferably ensure user has appropriate permissions on the vendor folder